# Yii2 Get Value from Related Model

Tags: php, yii2, relational-database

I have built this yii2 app where I have a model named **Customer**, and another named **Order**, where customer_id is the foreign key in **Order**.

I have created an action named **SendEmail**, which is used in the **Order** index page, and I need to get the email which the order will be sent to according to the customer_id.

So how can I get the email for the current **Order** according to the **Customer**?

Customer Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Customer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'customer';
    }
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['Name'], 'required'],
        [['Archive', 'Credit'], 'integer'],
        [['Address'], 'string'],
        [['Name', 'Email'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['Tel'], 'string', 'max' => 14],
        [['Category'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'Id' => 'ID',
        'Name' => 'Name',
        'Tel' => 'Tel',
        'Email' => 'Email',
        'Archive' => 'Archive',
        'Credit' => 'Credit',
        'Address' => 'Address',
        'Category' => 'Category'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['Customer_Id' => 'Id']);
}
}
```

And here is the action in the controller:

```
public function actionSendEmail($id)
{
    //Here I should get the email according to the customer_id

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {

            $value= Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom (['smth@hotmail.com'=>'Smth'])
            ->setTo ($model->Email)
            ->setSubject ("Price Offer")
            ->setHtmlBody ("Test")
            ->send();

        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id]);}
        else
            return $this -> render('create',['model'=>$model,]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you defined relation between two models in Yii 2?

Comment: Yes, I definitely did.

Comment: So what is exactly the problem here? You have got relation, you can fetch model and get the customer's email.

Comment: How can I do that? What I need is really simple, but I'm not so good at it.

Comment: Show `customer` model and probably related index code.

Comment: I provided the customer model, and the Order Controller

Answer (score 4):

You need to also declare the relationship in your Order model class:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ... Some code here ...

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['Id' => 'Customer_Id']);
    }
}
```

This way you can just get the email like this:

```
$email = $order->customer->Email;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define relations in your models, which in this case did, you can access the related data using relations easily either from customs to orders or vise o versa.

All you need to do is to access relation from the instance of model to the related model as a property.
For example if you have got costumer instance and need the orders you do this:

```
$customer->orders[i]->[property or method of the related model you demand access]
```

(Note that the `i` above is the index of customer's demanded order because the relation is `one to many` and customer may have multiple orders.)

And if you have one of the orders and you need to access the customer that ordered it you do this:

```
$order->customer->[property or method of the related model you demand access]
```

P.S: It is always a good practice to define relations in both of your models and in this case define it in both `customer` and `order` models.

You can understand relations and their definitions in `Yii2` by taking a look at [This Document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).